# Have I 'Started a Server' on Sublime Text or is there just a syntax error? (Sublime Text 3 - SFTP/FTP)

Tags: php, ftp, sftp

So, my question is basically this:

Why does my .php file look like this:
[image: Weird coloured .php file]
Instead of this:
[image: Regular coloured .php file]
? I'm speaking colour-wise here folks. I'll tell you when it happened. It was doing fine, but then I made the mistake of going into `File>SFTP/FTP` (A package that I have installed) and clicked on `Setup Server...`. It threw loads of code into my file and turned the colours around. I deleted all of the code hoping that it would sort it out, but it has stayed the same. Now I'm wondering if I just have a stupid syntax error or if I need to Unsetup the server or something. Here is the beginning of the .php file so you can see it closer up:

```
<?php

include_once 'dbconfig.php';

// if(!$user->is_loggedin()) {
//  $user->redirect('index.php');
// }

if($user->is_loggedin()) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
```

Am I just not seeing something? Or do I need to change something else?
I'm getting a 500 Internal Error and I think this could be the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hot pink is showing invalid syntax.

Comment: @sheplu Ok, but why? I can't see any syntax error!

Comment: first change your syntaxe highlight. You seems to be in JSON mode. Bottom right corner you can switch back to php

Comment: @sheplu Awesome! Thanks. That really was stupid :P